# SSIS Conditional Split - String Contains Numeric

Tags: ssis

Within an SSIS Conditional Split, how can I check if a string contains a numeric value, e.g.

```
behzad12behi2548
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these two cases with the addition of REPLACENULL function that handles cases where NULL would FINDSTRING in error

Case 1: string contains a numeric value

```
FINDSTRING(REPLACENULL(Column,""),"1",1) >= 1 || FINDSTRING(REPLACENULL(Column,""),"2",1) >= 1 ...
```

Case 2: string doesn't contain a numeric value

```
FINDSTRING(REPLACENULL(Column,""),"1",1) == 0 && FINDSTRING(REPLACENULL(Column,""),"2",1) == 0 ...
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

As the SSIS 'language' doesn't have a RegEx function, you have two options:

Search for a numeric character, as in

```
FINDSTRING(Address,"0",1) > 0 || FINDSTRING(Address,"1",1) > 0 || FINDSTRING(Address,"2",1) > 0  (etc)
```

-or- Write a script component that uses the C# Regex class.

I'd opt for the former, it's a lot easier.